# Customise wp_List_pages to output a UL LI

Tags: pagination, links

I am trying to get my pagination for posts outputted as a list. ie: UL > LI > A.

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

I see that I can add a UL easily enough by editing the $defaults but I cannot seem to wrap the a links in li's.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Arguments of wp_link_pages()

Maybe this will work for you:

```
$args = array(
                'before'           => '<ul><li>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
                'after'            => '</li></ul>',
                'link_before'      => '',
                'link_after'       => '',
                'next_or_number'   => 'number',
                'separator'        => '</li><li>',
                'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
                'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
                'pagelink'         => '%',
                'echo'             => 1
        );

 wp_link_pages( $args );
```

The output is for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Pages:</li>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> <a href="http://example.com/hello-world/2/">2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://example.com/hello-world/3/">3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://example.com/hello-world/4/">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can also use `'echo' => 0` to read it into a variable, where you can modify it further via regular expressions.

### Filters for wp_link_pages()

Another way is to use the filters `wp_link_pages` and / or `wp_link_pages_link`.

Here is an example:

```
function custom_wp_link_pages_link( $link )
{
    return '<li>' . $link . '</li>';
}
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link',  'custom_wp_link_pages_link' );
```

that will give you the following HTML output:

```
<ul> 
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> <a href="http://example.com/hello-world/2/">2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://example.com/hello-world/3/">3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://example.com/hello-world/4/">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

for

```
wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<ul>', 'after' => '</ul>' ) );
```